# Rails 4 - comment.create saves :text but not :commenter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create a new comment the text saves fine but the commenter is not being saved. I have verified that the column for commenter exists and that the parameter is being passed. The field just isn't inserting into the table and I have no clue why.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :new_comment %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, params[:user_id] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, params[:id] %>
    <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Action:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:text, :commenter))
    redirect_to show_post_path(@user, @post)
  end
```

Comment: where is the commenter field in the form?

Comment: Even without the commenter field, a parameter of 1 is still sent as the commenter. Its just not saving it.

Comment: is it coming through as `:commenter` or `:commenter_id` ? if the latter - you need to add it to the permitted fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more field in form which will pass commenter for comment

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :new_comment %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, params[:user_id] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, params[:id] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'comment[commenter]', params[:user_id] %>
    <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

OR

Change controller code to

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment].permit(:text, :commenter))
    @comment.commenter = @user.id
    @comment.save 
    redirect_to show_post_path(@user, @post)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want your `commenter_id` in your form instead of `user_id`. Change your `user_id` line in your form to:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :commenter_id, params[:commenter_id] %>
```

And then change the third line in your `create` function:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:text, :commenter_id))
```

Comment: I added the user and post id's as hidden fields so I could save the comment to the correct post more easily. The attribute is simply named "commenter". Thats the name of the column in the table as well as the name of the parameter I see passed on an error page or in the terminal.

Comment: Ah ok my mistake. In that case, how would you like to get the commenter value? Is it input in the form, or is it set in the controller or model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your association between User model and Comment Model?
in **User model** it should be has_many :comments  and in **Comment Model** belongs_to :user